# Как обработать на python одновременно поступившие webhook?

Tags: python, webhook

люди добрые! Я новичок в кодинге. Программа принимает данные json и заполняет форму на сайте.
Например:
{'citizenship': 'englishman', 'name': 'Sherlock', 'surname': 'Holmes', 'key': 'person'} и
{'citizenship': 'russian', 'name': 'Иван', 'surname': 'Иванов', 'key': 'person'}
В зависимости от 'citizenship', выбирает вкладку, заполняет и отправляет.
Иногда данные поступают одновременно. Тогда заполняет только одну форму. Либо на первую накладывается данные второго.
Код:

````py
    from flask import Flask, request, abort
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    
    def fill_form(data):
        name = driver.find_element_by_id('input_name')
        name.clear()
        name.send_keys(data['name'])
    
        surname = driver.find_element_by_id('input_surname')
        surname.clear()
        surname.send_keys(data['surname'])
        driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()
    
    
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def webhook():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.get_json()
            if data['key'] == 'person':
                fill_form(data)
                return '', 200
            else:
                abort(403)
        else:
            abort(400)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()

Вот так ругается:

    WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Connection pool is full, discarding connection: 127.0.0.1
Пробовал поставить задержку и менял значение. Не помогло.
```python
    from time import sleep
    def fill_form(data):
        name = driver.find_element_by_id('input_name')
        name.clear()
        name.send_keys(data['name'])
    
        surname = driver.find_element_by_id('input_surname')
        surname.clear()
        surname.send_keys(data['surname'])
        driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()
        sleep(0.5)
````

Comment: Встроенный flask-сервер предназначен только для разработки, и его ни в коем случае нельзя применять в боевом окружении. Используйте полноценные wsgi-серверы, такие как gunicorn и uwsgi

Answer (score -1):

использовать модуль queue для хранения данных

```
import queue
q=queue.Queue(2) #размер очереди
q.empty()
#True
q.full()
#False
q.put('мои данные')
q.get()
#'мои дынные'
```